# how to combine images with mp3 to look like video in android

Tags: android, audio, android-viewpager, mp3, viewpage

I am trying to **combine images in view-pager with mp3 audio file**.
I have **26 images** of ABC alphabets in **view-pager**, and a **ABC song in mp3 audio file.** I want that when i click start button mp3 song file play and alphabets images in view-pager changes.
I had searched a lot but didn't find any solution that i can understand. Can some one give me code of that?
Please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to solve your problem would be to create a timer and to simply switch between the bitmap at regular intervals.
When the start button is clicked, just launch the timer using an handler, and inside the timer event, add your logic to switch images.